# tensorflow-gpu is slower than tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I made neural nets with tensorflow
but tnesorflow-gpu is slower than cpu!

total running(training) time is 130sec in tensorflow 2.1
and 330sec in tensorflow-gpu 2.1

My CPU is i7-7th gen and GPU is geforce-930M(laptop environments)
It's because my GPU is slower than CPU?
If so, Can I setup to run GPU automatically in appropriate situation only?

(CUDA environments seems appropriately setup, also I manually checked that tensorflow 2.1 is using CPU only and tensorflow-gpu 2.1 is using both CPU and GPU.)

update : My neural network's size is 64 x 32 x 16 x 1(maybe not fitting in parallel execution) and in tensorflow 2.1, I turn off GPU by this commands as follows.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
```

Comment: Have you timed the whole script execution or only the fit method? It looks like a udge difference but I think that loading gpu can take some time. Also, what kind of network are you working with? Some networks architectures are less fit to parallel computation than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of TensorFlow 2.1, the GPU support is also available in the `tensorflow` package, not only `tensorflow-gpu`; if you use `import tensorflow as tf` it defaults to GPU usage if it finds one; I would personally first uninstall `tensorflow-gpu` and leave only the plain `tensorflow` package.